# Angular 9 Send email with mailto

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a problem sending email using `mailto`.
I have several emails in a grid and I would like to send a list of contacts by email.
When you click on the link if the list is empty, you should send an alert saying that you need to select an email to send. If the list has results, open a modal with the option to confirm the sending.

Grid

```
    <td class="text-center">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      (change)="setItemCheckEmails(email)"
                      value="{{ email }}">
                      {{ email.edEmail }}
                  </td>
<button
            type="button"
            (click)="checkSendEmail()" >Mail</button>
            <a href="{{ sendEmailList() }}" class="btn btn-secondary mr-2"
            (click)="enviarEmailModal.show()">SendE-mail</a>
```

Modal

```
<app-ui-modal #sendEmailModal [containerClick]="false">
  <div class="app-modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Check</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="app-modal-body">
    <p>Send email?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="app-modal-footer">
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-secondary"
      data-dismiss="modal"
      (click)="sendEmailModal.hide()">
      No
    </button>
    <button
      style="margin-left: 5px"
      (click)="sendEmail()"
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary"
      data-dismiss="modal">
      Yes
    </button>
  </div>
</app-ui-modal>

<app-ui-modal #errrSendEmailModal [containerClick]="false">
  <div class="app-modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title">Alerta</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="app-modal-body">
    <p>No emails found.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="app-modal-footer">
    <button
      style="margin-left: 5px"
      (click)="errorSendEmailModal.hide()"
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary"
      data-dismiss="modal">
      OK
    </button>
  </div>
</app-ui-modal>
```

Typescript

```
@ViewChild("enviarEmailModal") modalConfirmEmail;
@ViewChild("erroEnvioEmailModal") modalErroEmail;

setItemCheckEmails(val) {
    const index = this.emailsList.indexOf(val);
    if (index === -1) {
      this.emailsList.push(val);
    } else {
      this.emailsList.splice(index, 1);
    }

    if(this.emailsList!= null && this.emailsList.length > 0) {
      this.emailsList.forEach(email => {
        this.nameEmails.push(email.edEmail);
      });
    }
  }

  sendEmail() {
    if(this.emailsList != null && this.emailsList .length > 0) { 
      this.notificationService.notify("Alert");
    } else {
      this.sendEmailList();
    }
  }

 sendEmailList() {
    if(this.naneSkill != null && this.naneSkill.length > 0) {
      this.naneSkill.join(';');
      return 'mailto:'+this.naneSkill;
    }
  }

  checkSendEmail() {
    if(this.emailsList === null && this.emailsList .length === 0) { 
      this.notificationService.notify("Alert error email.");
    }
  }
```

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: It doesn't open the modal and when it opens it opens in the mail. The correct thing would be to open the modal, click on the button to confirm and send the email. And the link when I type the button does not work

Comment: mailto is a html feature to open the mail box application which the user has in his/her system. it does not send the email.

Comment: Yes, I understood. How do I open using <a href="">